# Snapchat's lenses skin smoothing effects in unity3d? achievable by shaders?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality, tracker

Snapchat lenses have a way to smooth the skin and whiten it in a way that you just look better (see attached photos). We are trying to create similar effects in unity3d but are not able to find any related answers. We are able to track the faces in the screen and retrieve the coordinates of feature points including brows, eyes, noses, mouth, but we don't know how to utilize these to smooth and whiten the skin.

Here are a couple of things that we thought we could do, but definitely need a lot of help from the community: 1. Are there any available shaders which does similar things to human faces? Like what we've found in OpenGL ES or GPUImage in iOS native app? 2. If not, do we have a way to export OpenGL libraries or native GPUImage libraries to unity3d so that we can work this out?[image: Face under Snapchat beautifying lenses] [image: normal face]